# How would I go about implementing an OSX (desktop) Core Location provider?

Tags: macos, gps, core-location, provider

I want to use Mac OSX for a location application, but want to provide fake location data (via a GPS log file). How would I go about implementing this? I've looked at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/index.html but it only talks about USING the framework, not about how it gets its location information. I've implemented location providers for the Android platform, but seen nothing so far about core location.

There is clearly an interface for it: if it is copied from iOS I know there is a super-secret Bluetooth GPS protocol to provide location information from GPS devices (there is at least one device that does so) and I expect a similar hook is somewhere in OSX.

Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if you ever find a solution, I have a similar requirement. Thnx

Comment: Are you trying to provide GPS data to other apps, or is it your own app that you want to simulate?

Comment: I have an Android app that implements a Bluetooth GPS data source: I'm trying to connect it via Bluetooth to my Mac and get a CoreLocation provider.